# Web browser component javascript behaves like IE8, but in user agent says IE10

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, configuration, sap-gui

We have a SPA application which should be shown in SAP HtmlViewer Component (http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/c9/147a36c70d2354e10000009b38f839/content.htm). 
According to docs the component should use the system browser, which is IE10 or on some stations IE11.

The problem is that the javascript engine behaves like the one in IE8. There are missing functions such as Array.isArray, addEventListener, Object.isExtensible etc., which leads me to believe that the brwser engine is IE8. However, when we check the user agent string it says IE10/Trident6.0, which is IE10. I am using this code to test javascript:

```
        alert('test string.trim  ' + str.trim);
        alert('test Array.map  ' + arr.map);
        alert('test Object.isExtensible  ' + Object.isExtensible );
        alert('test Object.defineProperty  ' + Object.defineProperty );
```

, and the first three are undefined.

Also, jQuery 2+ does not work (addEventListener undefiend, isArray undefined etc.), but jQuery 1 does work.

I have tried to include X-UA-Compatibility meta tag and http headers with IE=EDGE to force behavior of the newest browser (though I thing it just change document rendering and not the javascript features), but to no avail.

I also checked the registry [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION] on the computer where the SAP client is running and there is set SAPLOGON.EXE set to 0x02710 (which is IE10 according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx).

The questions are:

- are there any properties in windows system to force web browser components (which uses the system browser) to use old implementation of javascript or disallow some of the methods?
- particularly in SAP, is it possible to force HtmlViewer component to behave in terms of javascript differently?
- or more generally, does have anybody idea why this could be happening?

Any help will be be appreciated.

Comment: On 64 bit Windows also check `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\...` and also the corresponding key in HKCU

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, I originally looked into Wo6432Node, there were no subkeys. However, I will double check ... .